# function deactivate_plugins does not exist

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I am getting `function deactivate_plugins does not exist` error when calling this function

```
function deactivateSelf(){
    deactivate_plugins(RSD_PLUGIN, true); //gives error: function deactivate_plugins does not exist
    header("Location: plugins.php?deactivate=true"); //redirect to plugin management with message
    die();
}
```

- the function `deactivate_plugins` is on the server in `/wp-admin/wp-includes/plugin.php`
- the function deactivateSelf works on my developer's computer but not on my linode server
- I downloaded http://www.turnkeylinux.org/wordpress, which should have pretty standard configuration and I got the same error. I tried to upgrade wp to the latest version and still got the same error.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Just for clarity: Did you add that bounty to give an extra reward to toscho or do you need extra help?

Comment: @Jan: I added bounty after I tried what @toscho suggested. Unfortunatelly I tried to add not the correct plugin.php. toscho edided the answer and I saw that I have to use different path to plugin.php

Comment: so, now everything is fine and working. I need to wait to give toscho the bounty ... I already accepted the answer because it answered my question.

Comment: also noticed that `'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php '` is not valid in PHP. Notice the extra space after php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The file `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` is not always included. You may have to do this in your plugin.

And your `Location` header is invalid: You have to send a complete URL.

You should use:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
```

When do you call this function? Maybe too early.

Comment: I added `require_once('full_path_to/plugin.php');` but it didn't help. Header is now commented out.

Comment: If you're still getting "function does not exist" errors after supplying the full path to the file that initializes the function, either the function is getting unregistered somewhere or your path is incorrect. I'd try this again, but try using require_once(get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');. You should probably be logged in for this to work; I remember reading somewhere that function doesn't work outside wp-admin (though I may be wrong).

Comment: there are two `includes` directories one in `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` in wp root directory. The first one is the right one. Thank you.

Comment: do you put this code in wp-config.php or functions?

Comment: @v3nt Into the same plugin that is deactivated.

Comment: ? sorry don't follow. What file does this code go into. ie wp-config.php or functions.php ? Tried both getting errors.

Comment: @v3nt Both are wrong, as I said. Add it to the **plugin** code.

Comment: @toscho - i added it to functions.php and it works there. Great for local & staging development.

Comment: @v3nt This is the [worst place](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) for that code. Really, please use a plugin. :)