# Disable the "remember me" to wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin

I Look long enough to find the solution of my problem. Really, Is there any way to disable the "Remember me" to wp-admin? I want to disable it for safety reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript (jQuery) or outputbuffering. A combination of both (outputbuffering and JS) are in the script below.

PHP:

```
namespace WPSE77581;

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'WPSE77581\remove_forgetmenot', 10, 0 );

function remove_forgetmenot() {

    add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'WPSE77581\enqueue_script', 10, 0 );

    add_action( 'login_head', 'WPSE77581\start_outputbuffer', 1, 0 );
    add_action( 'login_footer', 'WPSE77581\end_outputbuffer', 1, 0 );

}

function enqueue_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'WPSE77581-remove-forgetmenot',
        plugins_url( 'wpse77581.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery' ),
        false,
        true
    );

}

function start_outputbuffer() {

    ob_start();

}

function end_outputbuffer() {

    $html = ob_get_clean();

    $search = '#<p class="forgetmenot">.+</p>#Uuis';

    $html = preg_replace( $search, '', $html );

    echo $html;

}
```

JS [wpse77581.js]:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
    function ( $ ) {
        $( '.forgetmenot' ).remove();
    }
);
```

Both solutions has it's assets and drawbacks. Using outputbuffering can be a bit tricky if other plugins use outputbuffering too. JavaScript can be disabled in the visitors browser. Outputbuffering manipulate the DOM **before** it is send to the browser, JS **after** it was send to the browser.

**Update**

Why does the plugin code does not work in my `functions.php`?

To answer this question, we have to take a closer look at the hooks and have to understand **when** and **what** happened while WordPress is loading. At first the working code for the `functions.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * Remove forgetmenot-checkbox on login screen
 * Uses the hook 'after_theme_setup' instead of 'plugins_loaded' because
 * first the theme have to be setup for get_template_directory_uri()
 *
 * @uses add_action()
 * @hook after_setup_theme
 */
add_action(
    'after_setup_theme',
    'WPSE77581_remove_forgetmenot',
    10,
    0
);

/**
 * Hook up all actions and filters
 *
 * @uses add_action()
 * @hook login_enqueue_scripts
 * @hook login_head
 * @hook login_footer
 */
function WPSE77581_remove_forgetmenot() {

    // add JavaScript
    add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'WPSE77581_enqueue_script', 10, 0 );

    // plain PHP with outputbuffering
    add_action( 'login_head', 'WPSE77581_start_outputbuffer', 1, 0 );
    add_action( 'login_footer', 'WPSE77581_end_outputbuffer', 1, 0 );

}

/**
 * Enqueueing needed JavaScripts
 * JS is stored in the folder 'js' inside the theme folder
 *
 * @uses wp_enqueue_script
 * @uses get_template_directory_uri()
 */
function WPSE77581_enqueue_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'WPSE77581-remove-forgetmenot',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wpse77581.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        false,
        true
    );

}

/**
 * Start outputbuffering
 * Buffers the DOM for later manipulation
 */
function WPSE77581_start_outputbuffer() {

    ob_start();

}

/**
 * End outputbuffering
 * Get the content from outputbuffer and remove the paragraph with checkbox
 */
function WPSE77581_end_outputbuffer() {

    $html = ob_get_clean();

    $search = '#<p class="forgetmenot">.+</p>#Uuis';

    $html = preg_replace( $search, '', $html );

    echo $html;

}
```

Where are the differences to the plugin code? At first it is no longer a plugin and so we can not use `plugins_url()` to get the uri to the JavaScript. After a search in the Codex, we find the function `[get_template_directory_uri()][1]` to get the correct path to the JavaScript file.

After simply changing from `plugins_url()` to `get_template_directory_uri()` the code does not work. Now we have to start thinking. The code is no longer a plugin code, it is now a 'theme' or 'template' code. Can we use the hook `plugins_loaded` for a theme code?

It seems that this is not a good idea. To understand why this is not a good idea, we have a look inside the core files (in this case take `wp-settings.php`). As we read the core files, we find the line with `do_action('plugins_loaded');`. Until this point, no theme was setup and so `get_template_directory_uri()` does not know anything about a template directory.
Continue reading the core file, we will find the part where the theme is setup. And we also find a line with `do_action('after_setup_theme');`. This seems to be a good point to hook up our code. After replacing `plugins_loaded` with `after_setup_theme` and test the code, we see the code will work.

**If you want to develop plugins and / or themes for WordPress, you need to understand when and what happened while WordPress is loaded! If you get stuck, take a brief minute and start reading the core files.**

Happy new year.

Comment: `unset( $_POST['rememberme'] );` might help too.

Comment: i create a `function:remove_remember_me.php` with the 1st part of code in .php and i call this for:`require_once('includes/admin/remove_remember_me.php');`, also i create a js with the 2nd part of code and i call this to `function.php` with `<?php wp_enqueue_script('disable_me.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'includes/js/disable_me.js',array('jquery'),'1.0',true);?>`, but this is not work. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: First at all: Do you use PHP5.2 or PHP5.3? Namespaces are available since PHP5.3! Create a plugin, do not put everything in your functions.php (see [discussion](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) ). This function is **not** theme specific. So put it in a plugin. I create a gist which can be downloaded https://gist.github.com/4408787 This plugin works for me fine at PHP5.3 and PHP5.2 (both versions are included)

Comment: Thanks for help. I used PHP Version 5.4.7. I read the discussion and i will be back.

Comment: @Ralf912, i read in **github** the `readme.txt`, and and I realized that is plugin. But i don't use with plugin method, but only with custom method (php file and js). Αny help on my question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ralf912, i upload this file with plugin method and it is works. But, as I said above I want to do this with custom **php** and **js**.

Comment: @MikeD With **custom php** and **js** you mean, code in your functions php? It does not work, because the theme was not setup (and so functions like `get_theme_directory_uri()´) when the hook 'plugins_loaded' is fired. I updated the gist with a new file. Copy&paste the code from this file to your `functions.php` and copy the JS into a folder named `js` inside your theme folder. Happy new year.

Comment: @Ralf912, yes i mean that thing. I'll do it again from scratch, and i am come back with questions and impressions. Happy new year, too. Thanks.

Comment: @Ralf912. Following your advice, and the plugin with custom php and js, works. I hope that i have not problem in the future. Happy new year, again.