# How to stop WordPress showing a virtual Robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I can see the robots.txt file here :

http://persian.cc/robots.txt

But Google can't !

I know that I can find `robots.txt` files in the root of a website, but hey there is no robots.txt file in mine and this `robots.txt` is a virtual one being made by WordPress. Now how to stop wordpress doing that?

OR If I cannot stop wordpress showing that virtual `robots.txt` file, how can I stop Google looking for it on my website? maybe a `.htaccess` code or something?

Comment: Your robots.txt seems to be empty, right?

Comment: Just create your own robots.txt and google / bots will take that one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I want to know how to stop wordpress creating such a thing dynamically.

Comment: There should be a way to turn off this "feature" entirely. Adding a filter is not an ideal solution, also it only affects the one theme via functions.php and only the one blog. This should be configurable via wp-config.php and/or make this an "opt-in" feature! Making this mandatory is a huge pain. Also it seems to break DuckDuckGo!

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Create a static file `robots.txt`. Highly recommended.
2. Filter `'robots_txt'`:

   ```
   add_filter( 'robots_txt', 'wpse_77969_robots' );

   function wpse_77969_robots()
   {
       status_header( 204 );
       return '';
   }
   ```

Comment: @ParsaPejvak See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php – I recommend a plugin. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added the code, but now it shows the root page. Please check http://persian.cc/robots.txt | I need it to return a 404 so that google would understand there is no robots.txt

Comment: The problem is resolved, I just added this: RedirectMatch 404 "robots.txt" in the .htaccess file. Though Thanks

Comment: Is this code still working? It didn't work for me. Also I think Googlebot prefers a 404 or 200, but no guarantees LOL. Why is WordPress generating robots.txt now? What a pain!