# xmlrpc_enabled filter not called

Tags: filters, xml-rpc

Since WordPress 3.5, the core developers have decided to keep xml rpc enabled by default and there are no options in the Admin to disable it.

This blog post explains how to disable it by modifying the xmlrpc_enabled filter

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I still get the following on the generated HTML

```
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://domain.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
```

and WordPress still generates the `http://example.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd` page

I'm putting the filter in the `functions.php` file of my theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the HTML link:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );
```

To stop all requests to `xmlrpc.php` for [RSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Really_Simple_Discovery) per XML-RPC:

```
if ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) && XMLRPC_REQUEST ) )
    exit;
```

This is plugin territory. [Never use this code in a theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).

Comment: I'm building an app in WordPress (and thus putting all functionality in the theme). Otherwise, I'm aware of the rsd_link action, but looking for clean way to switch off xml rpc.

Comment: There is no reason to build an app as theme, quite contrary it should be a plugin. You can use `register_theme_directory()` to add a custom theme from the directory of your plugin.

Comment: I was going the plugin way, but found that using a Theme will help me avoid many headaches with `register_theme_directory()`, so I did it the easy way ;).

Comment: As you can see `xmlrpc.php` is out of reach for a theme.

Comment: I thought the choice had to do with semantics. Does that mean that functions.php has some limitations? If so, where can I find these limitations?

Comment: @OmarAbid Looking again at the source, the theme is called, so I stand corrected. Sorry for the confusion. :) Themes cannot replace pluggable functions, that is the most important limitation.