# Lost password and back to blog in same line

Tags: customization, login

I would like put on the same line "Lost your password?" and "Back to Blog/Site" links.

While I'm posting that I take a look to this post and found my solution: [Positioning the “Lost your password?” and “← Back to Site”](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81653/positioning-the-lost-your-password-and-%E2%86%90-back-to-site)

I've posted that for if it helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution. I added via functions.php the following:

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .login #backtoblog{
          float: right;
          position: relative;
          top: -35px;
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

That code move to right side and a little to top the 'Back to Blog/site' link.

Hope that helps!

Comment: For your information. If you find the answer satisfactory, you **can** [accept your own answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). It shows other users that a working solution does exist.