# Reset Roles (or undo role changes on theme change)

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, deactivation, reset

I am creating a theme that deletes some user roles that are not necessary and creates others.  (It deletes author and contributor and renames subscriber).

Everything works, but on theme deactivation, I want to readd all the roles I deleted.  Do I have to manually go in and create the roles (author and contributor), manually adding in all the capabilities listed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities ?

There are two reasons I don't want to do this:

1. More code.
2. If capabilities and roles get updated, on every Wordpress update I'll have to manually check I'm adding the right capabilities back.

There must be a better solution for undoing all role changes I made on deactivation.  Right?

Comment: What code are you using when deactivation occurs? :::: IMO, *Reason 1* is not reasonable...

Comment: There's no reason to add roles to Themes. This is functionality that belongs to a plugin and nowhere else. Also you shouldn't _delete_ roles, just add your own ones and use capability mapping (or go with default capabilities - even better).

Comment: I take your point. I'm also developing a plugin alongside the theme.  I'll do the role changes there now.  Where you see theme read plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a plugin to manage roles, [not a theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php). Roles are not for presentation.

In your plugin use `register_activation_hook()` and `register_deactivation_hook()` to add or remove new roles. Do not remove built-in roles, other plugins may rely on their existence.

Comment: Okay, I've accepted the answer, which is what I feared: default roles should not be deleted so there should be no need to create the defaults back.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will reset a WordPress default role to it's default capabilities. Note: these defaults are for WordPress 3.5, any other versions might have different defaults. To be safe, **only use this code on WordPress 3.5**.

#### Warning

This cannot be undone! The role, in it's current state, is removed and recreated with it's default values.

```
/*
 * example usage: $results = reset_role_wpse_82378( 'subscriber' );
 * per add_role() (WordPress Codex):
 * $results "Returns a WP_Role object on success, null if that role already exists."
 *
 * possible $role values:
 * 'administrator'
 * 'editor'
 * 'author'
 * 'contributor'
 * 'subscriber'
 */
function reset_role_wpse_82378( $role ) {
    $default_roles = array(
        'administrator' => array(
            'switch_themes' => 1,
            'edit_themes' => 1,
            'activate_plugins' => 1,
            'edit_plugins' => 1,
            'edit_users' => 1,
            'edit_files' => 1,
            'manage_options' => 1,
            'moderate_comments' => 1,
            'manage_categories' => 1,
            'manage_links' => 1,
            'upload_files' => 1,
            'import' => 1,
            'unfiltered_html' => 1,
            'edit_posts' => 1,
            'edit_others_posts' => 1,
            'edit_published_posts' => 1,
            'publish_posts' => 1,
            'edit_pages' => 1,
            'read' => 1,
            'level_10' => 1,
            'level_9' => 1,
            'level_8' => 1,
            'level_7' => 1,
            'level_6' => 1,
            'level_5' => 1,
            'level_4' => 1,
            'level_3' => 1,
            'level_2' => 1,
            'level_1' => 1,
            'level_0' => 1,
            'edit_others_pages' => 1,
            'edit_published_pages' => 1,
            'publish_pages' => 1,
            'delete_pages' => 1,
            'delete_others_pages' => 1,
            'delete_published_pages' => 1,
            'delete_posts' => 1,
            'delete_others_posts' => 1,
            'delete_published_posts' => 1,
            'delete_private_posts' => 1,
            'edit_private_posts' => 1,
            'read_private_posts' => 1,
            'delete_private_pages' => 1,
            'edit_private_pages' => 1,
            'read_private_pages' => 1,
            'delete_users' => 1,
            'create_users' => 1,
            'unfiltered_upload' => 1,
            'edit_dashboard' => 1,
            'update_plugins' => 1,
            'delete_plugins' => 1,
            'install_plugins' => 1,
            'update_themes' => 1,
            'install_themes' => 1,
            'update_core' => 1,
            'list_users' => 1,
            'remove_users' => 1,
            'add_users' => 1,
            'promote_users' => 1,
            'edit_theme_options' => 1,
            'delete_themes' => 1,
            'export' => 1,
        ),
        'editor' => array(
            'moderate_comments' => 1,
            'manage_categories' => 1,
            'manage_links' => 1,
            'upload_files' => 1,
            'unfiltered_html' => 1,
            'edit_posts' => 1,
            'edit_others_posts' => 1,
            'edit_published_posts' => 1,
            'publish_posts' => 1,
            'edit_pages' => 1,
            'read' => 1,
            'level_7' => 1,
            'level_6' => 1,
            'level_5' => 1,
            'level_4' => 1,
            'level_3' => 1,
            'level_2' => 1,
            'level_1' => 1,
            'level_0' => 1,
            'edit_others_pages' => 1,
            'edit_published_pages' => 1,
            'publish_pages' => 1,
            'delete_pages' => 1,
            'delete_others_pages' => 1,
            'delete_published_pages' => 1,
            'delete_posts' => 1,
            'delete_others_posts' => 1,
            'delete_published_posts' => 1,
            'delete_private_posts' => 1,
            'edit_private_posts' => 1,
            'read_private_posts' => 1,
            'delete_private_pages' => 1,
            'edit_private_pages' => 1,
            'read_private_pages' => 1,
        ),
        'author' => array(
            'upload_files' => 1,
            'edit_posts' => 1,
            'edit_published_posts' => 1,
            'publish_posts' => 1,
            'read' => 1,
            'level_2' => 1,
            'level_1' => 1,
            'level_0' => 1,
            'delete_posts' => 1,
            'delete_published_posts' => 1,
        ),
        'contributor' => array(
            'edit_posts' => 1,
            'read' => 1,
            'level_1' => 1,
            'level_0' => 1,
            'delete_posts' => 1,
        ),
        'subscriber' => array(
            'read' => 1,
            'level_0' => 1,
        ),
        'display_name' => array(
            'administrator' => 'Administrator',
            'editor'        => 'Editor',
            'author'        => 'Author',
            'contributor'   => 'Contributor',
            'subscriber'    => 'Subscriber',
        ),
    );
    $role = strtolower( $role );
    remove_role( $role );
    return add_role( $role, $default_roles['display_name'][$role], $default_roles[$role] );
} // function reset_role_wpse_82378
```