# Notifications Bar on home page only

Tags: plugins, posts, functions, wp-admin, notifications

Is it possible to create an "Alert" button that can be turned on and off thru wp-admin.
Of course the "Alert" button im asking for is to be published at the main page, but can only be turned on when its needed.

Im using wordpress with jqueryMobile for your information.

**EDIT:**

Its pretty hard to explain this. But i found this plugin and it does what im after. Except this plugin show the notification on everypage - even wp-admin.

To the question:

**Is it possible to create a notification/menubar that can be tunerd on/off from wp-admin. The idea behind this is to show important "news" whenever.**?

**Whats the best solution?**

Comment: I don't understand what the code you posted has to do with the description of what you are trying... If you want like a checkbox in the admin area that will be used to enable/disable something in the frontend, take a look at the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). So, in your template you'd have `if(get_option('alert_button')) echo 'Alert!';`.

Comment: Yeah something like that. Lets say i have 4 menu buttons. I want the 5th page just to "be turned on" when i need to it show within the 4 button. Do you understand ? With other words, it will always excist in wp-admin i just need to activate and deactivate control.

Comment: Research using the hints I gave and upgrade the Question, what you ask ain't difficult, but that downvote (not mine) clearly indicates the Q needs improvement.

Comment: Thanks you! Im already lookin in to it. And the question is now updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the very example from the Codex in the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) section. [**Put it**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) in the theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'eg_settings_api_init');

function eg_settings_api_init() {
    add_settings_section(
        'eg_setting_section',
        'Example settings section in reading',
        'eg_setting_section_callback_function',
        'reading'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'eg_setting_name',
        'Example setting Name',
        'eg_setting_callback_function',
        'reading',
        'eg_setting_section'
    );

    register_setting('reading','eg_setting_name');
}

function eg_setting_section_callback_function() {
    echo '<p>Intro text for our settings section</p>';
}

function eg_setting_callback_function() {
    echo '<input name="eg_setting_name" 
        id="gv_thumbnails_insert_into_excerpt" 
        type="checkbox" 
        value="1" 
        class="code" ' 
        . checked( 1, get_option('eg_setting_name'), false ) 
        . ' />Explanation text';
}
```

This creates a checkbox in `Settings > Reading`:
[image: settings api]

And in the theme `header.php` file, it can be used to render a big red warning banner:

```
<?php 
    if( get_option('eg_setting_name') ) {
        echo '<h1 style="background-color: #fcc;width:100%;height:3em;line-height:3em;text-align:center;top:40px;position:fixed">
            Warning!
            </h1>';
    }
?>
```