# Custom Metabox Not Saving

Tags: custom-field, functions, metabox

I've simplified a problem of saving custom metaboxes on update and still can't get the box to save the custom-field input to the database.

This is the call from `functions.php` to an external file `/metaboxes/home-meta-new.php`:

```
    // Loading Home Page Meta Box Code from External .php file
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page','load_home_meta' );
    function load_home_meta() {
        $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];
        if($post_id == '104'){
            include( get_template_directory() . '/metaboxes/home-meta-new.php' );
        }
    }
```

That part works as it shows the one meta box from the `home-meta-new.php` file.

Unfortunately, once values are input for the custom-fields and the user clicks update, the post refreshes without saving the values. Here is the `home-meta-new.php` code:

```
    <?php

    /**
     * Home Page Custom Meta Content
     *
    **/

add_meta_box(  
    'home_meta_box', // $id  
    'Home Page Content', // $title   
    'show_home_meta_box', // $callback  
    'page', // $page  
    'normal', // $context  
    'high'); // $priority       

    // Creating Array for Fields
    $prefix = '_home_';
    global $home_meta_fields;
    $home_meta_fields = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H2 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Sub Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H3 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Caption',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Caption Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 1140px wide x 530px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        )
    );// end home_meta array

    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box() {
    global $home_meta_fields, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce('home_upper_nonce').'" />';
    //wp_nonce_field( 'home_upper_nonce', 'home_upper_nonce' );

        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }// end build metabox callback

    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields;  

        // verify nonce 

        //option one 
        //if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            //return $post_id;  

            //option two
            if (isset($_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'])){
                if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'], 'home_upper_nonce' ) )
                    return;
            }else{return;}

        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  

        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            //if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                    if ($new && ($new != $old)) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta');
    // end save_home_meta

    ?>
```

Anyone able to identify where it's choking on the save? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding some dies inside your save_home_meta to see how far your code is getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do that `include`, you are trying to add the `save_post` hook inside the `add_meta_boxes_$post_type` hook. It should be independent.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page','load_home_meta' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_home_meta' );

// Declare all callback functions
```

Also, you shouldn't declare a function inside a function. Maybe you should consider creating a plugin for handling this, see: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615).
Or, if you *really want* it inside your theme's `functions.php`, do a `include` for all this meta box code.

You'll find plenty of working examples here, check this search query:
[+save_post +add_meta_box is:answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bsave_post%20%2badd_meta_box%20is%3aanswer)

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo... Will test that out... Figured that was what I was hanging on. Also, I thought I *had* done an `include` in the code above (just bundled the save_post action inside the add_meta_boxes_page action). thx