# Merging PHP download script into `functions.php`

Tags: theme-development, functions, wpdb, filesystem

I run a large mixtape download site on WordPress. I'm currently developing a new theme and I'd like to include as much site functionality into the theme's `functions.php`.

For serving the downloads, I have several PHP scripts. A download is called by a visitor by clicking on URL (example): `http://www.tjoonz.com/house.php?id=1234&file=post-slug`.
The script sanitizes the parameters and serves the `MP3` files from a private server directory. My main concern is that these scripts contain the database connection details, which is something I would much rather use `$wpdb` for.

## Current scripts (for reference)

My apologies if this is a bit excessive, but it may come in handy later. You can probably skip this bit for now if you're just reading my question.

### PHP

```
<?php // Tjoonz.com download script v1.2

// test arguments
if(!isset($_REQUEST['id']) || empty($_REQUEST['id']) || !isset($_REQUEST['file']) || empty($_REQUEST['file'])) 
{
    // invalid argument(s), abort script
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    die();
}

// set variables
$current_time = time();
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$post_id = $_GET['id'];
$file_requested = $_GET['file'];
$file_name = strip_tags($file_requested);
$file_path = '/home/tjoonz/audio/house/';
$locked = false;

// test if cookie 'downloadsAllowed' is set
// this prevents hotlinking on other domains for users who haven't visited Tjoonz.com yet
if ($_COOKIE["downloadsAllowed"] == "tj00nz")
{   
    $file_full = $file_path.$file_name;
    if (file_exists($file_full)) // test if requested mixtape exists
    {
        // establish connection to database for Play Counter test
        $user="#######";
        $password="#######";
        $database="#######";
        $host="#######";
        mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
        mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

        // set timerange to 2 hours ago (right now minus 7200 seconds)
        $timerange = $current_time - 7200;
        // get all records from 'playcount_lock' table
        $locks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playcount_lock WHERE request_time > $timerange") or die(mysql_error()); 

        // test if current IP address has already accessed this mixtape in the last 2 hours
        while ($lock = mysql_fetch_object($locks))
        {
            // set variables with data from record
            $lock_ip = $lock->ip_address;
            $lock_id = $lock->post_id;
            $lock_time = $lock->request_time;

            // compare record data with current user data
            if($lock_ip == $user_ip && $lock_id == $post_id && ($lock_time + 7200) >= $current_time)
            {
                // match found, break out of while loop and continue with script
                $locked = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$locked) // if playcounter is not locked, update the database
        { 
            // add a lock entry for the next two hours
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `playcount_lock` (`request_time`, `post_id`, `ip_address`) VALUES ('$current_time', '$post_id', '$user_ip')") or die(mysql_error());

            // update the play counter for this mixtape
            $post_meta = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_played' AND `post_id` = ".$post_id);
            $count = @mysql_result($post_meta, 0);

            if($count == FALSE)
            {
                // if no plays are present, insert the metadata into table
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (".$post_id.",'_played',1)");
            }
            else
            {
                // otherwise increase the existing number of plays by 1
                $newCount = mysql_result($post_meta, 0) + 1;
                mysql_query("UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value = ".$newCount." WHERE `meta_key` = '_played' AND `post_id` = ".$post_id);
            }
        }

        // we're done with the database, kill the connection
        mysql_close();

        // finally, send the file
        header("X-SENDFILE: ".$file_full);
        header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file_full));
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file_full));
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    }
    else // couldn't find that mixtape
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    }

}
else // cookie 'downloadsAllowed' not set, redirecting user to mixtape page
{
    $file_redirection = substr($file_name,0, -4);
    header("Location: http://www.tjoonz.com/house/" . $file_redirection . "/");
}

?>
```

### JS

```
// when playnow is clicked, add to myPlaylist and immediately start playing the mixtape
$("body").on("click", ".jplayer-playnow", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // add to Play Queue and play it immediately
    $.jPlayer.timeFormat.showHour = true;
    $.jPlayer.timeFormat.sepHour = ":";
    $.jPlayer.timeFormat.sepMin = ":";
    $.jPlayer.timeFormat.sepSec = "";
    myPlaylist.add({
        title: $(".single-title-mixtape").text(),
        artist: $(".single-title-artist").text(),
        genre: $(".jplayer-playnow span").attr("class"),
        mp3: $(this).attr("href"),                       // <--- This is where my problem comes up for my new theme, keep reading
        poster: $(".wp-post-image").attr("src")
    }, true); // true value here makes the newly added track play immediately
});
```

## Intentions

I'm using the current script twofold: When a user clicks the `PLAY` button, jQuery prevents the link from being navigated to, and takes the URL to instruct a music player to get the file instead. When a user clicks the `DOWNLOADS` button, the browser just follows through and a direct download is initiated. Both buttons use the same scripts and the same URLs.

In my new script I want to combine `house.php`, `electro.php`, `dubstep.php`, `drum-and-bass.php` and `techno.php` with a single script that take a `genre` parameter. Additionally, depending on how things go from here, I'll add a parameter to specify the `action` (download or play).

I intend to completely embed the script inside `functions.php`. On a mixtape page, two links would be:

```
<!--Play-->
<a href="?id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>&file=<?php tjnz_slug(); ?>&genre=<?php echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>&action=play">Play</a>
<!--Download-->
<a href="?id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>&file=<?php tjnz_slug(); ?>&genre=<?php echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>&action=download">Download</a>
```

## The problem

In my old script, I simply caught play links (by class name on the anchor) and prevented the default browser action, then do my things. I was able to do this because I could point to a 'real' file (e.g. `house.php`).

If I were to stick the code inside `functions.php`, how can I instruct my music player where the audio file is located? The audio file doesn't necessarily have to be an `MP3` file, as is evident by my current code: I instruct jPlayer that the audio file is located at house.php for example.

How do I tell jPlayer that the file is now coming from the mysterious `functions.php`? Do I link directly to `theme dir/functions.php`? Doesn't sound like a good idea, but that's just my gut feeling.

Like I said before, the main reason I want the script to be inside `functions.php` is so that I can tap into the power of `$wpdb`. If a separate PHP file is still the way to go, I'd still accept that answer (provided you've backed up that theory).

Comment: Maybe you should consider moving all this to a plugin and let `functions.php` deal with exclusively theme related issues. This Q&A may help to clarify things: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

Comment: It seems that, by that article's logic, this code would definitely belong inside a plugin. I personally avoid plugins so I'm not really proficient in that area. If I were to stick the code into a private plugin, how would I call its functions (as proposed by @user28206)? Is there an easy way to 'pluginify' my code?

Comment: Well, the plugin being active, you can call its functions from the theme. The matter is not converting `functions.php` into a big mess and being able to swap themes and not lose this functionality. You can surely organize `functions.php` by including external files. Anyway, it's up to you follow one path or another after reading the shortcomings in that Q&A and linked/related ones. [tag:plugin-development] isn't complex and is well documented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be calling stuff directly from the `functions.php` file by URL reference.

The `functions.php` is loaded in with the WordPress theme and it makes functions available to you from within the theme template files.

Most of your code can be ported directly into the `functions.php` but you will have to wrap some sort of interface around it which can be called within a page template.

If I were doing this I would likely put some PHP code in the index.php of the theme, right a the top to have a look at what's in the `$_REQUEST` object, like you do at the start of your PHP code.

Then, rather than execute the PHP you already have, you would call functions that are within your `functions.php` file that deal with the actual DB connections and serving the file.

As you mentioned, you'll have to use the `$wpdb` global variable to read the tables and the good news is that because you're working within the WordPress session, you don't have to authenticate with the DB so no UN/PW info.

Your JS will be best served in a separate file within your theme and loaded into WordPress properly by using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Okay, this is indeed a nice solution. I could then direct to `http://www.tjoonz.com?<params>` and the index PHP code would take the parameters and call the functions that are defined in functions.php. The pieces are falling into place now. I will try this approach out this weekend. In the mean time, have a nice +1 good sir!

Comment: Extra question: is it possible to do a `POST` with AJAX to access `functions.php` directly, and receive the audio file as response? I am already using AJAX to update my database using functions that are defined in `functions.php`, using `add_action('wp_ajax_tjnz-vote','tjnz_vote');`. I'm not too familiar with AJAX yet, so I'm wondering if it could handle `header` responses from `functions.php`, and serve the audio file in, for example, `$.ajax().success(function($audiostream) {...});`