# Email Subscribe for Downloads in Wordpress

Tags: users, email

I have a wordpress blog. I want to allow download files for only subscribers. How can I do that ? Any help would be appreciated.

Also when I get the email of user, the user must be subscriber first and then can download the file or files.

I removed feedburner I have nothing. I want only that to download any file subscriber condition for visitors. Like in the [androidhive](http://androidhive.info)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100939/simple-solution-for-restricting-access-to-some-uploads-downloads

Comment: thanks for answer. But what I want is not there. I want email subscriber not wordpress user. I need that.

Comment: Wordpress has no email subscribers feature. So first you have to write code or use plugin to handle this feature. After that you can restrict access to email subscribers. How-to this 2nd part depends on how you implement 1st part. So answer this question with the full workflow is impossible in a single answer: question should be written in a way that an user can aswer in few paragraphs. Maybe try to edit your question being more specific.

Comment: I am using now the Feedburner in my blog, can we use it like I say?

Comment: Sincerly I don't know. Edit your question with this info, trying to well explain what you have now and what you want to get, and maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not the best solution. It is a simple solution that can be / should be improved and it is intended only to give you a direction.

Create a CPT 'resource'.

```
register_post_type('resource', $args);
```

For args refer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Under your WP root folder (the one where you have `/wp-admin`, `/wp-includes` and `/wp-content`), via FTP add another folder, name it `/resources`.

In this folder create an `.htaccess` file with:

```
Options All -Indexes
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
```

Upload in this folder all your resource files.

Start creating your resource posts. Create it normally: title, content, taxonomies: whatever you want.

Use custom fields to link these posts with resource files, using the key: 'resource'

[image]

After that create you template file: `single-resource.php`

In this file create your for form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="resource" value="<?php the_the_ID() ?>">
  <p>Enter your email here to download:<br />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="">
  </p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

In this file you should implement some js validation, that I skip for semplicity.

In a plugin or in your `functions.php` create code that handle the form submission:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'maybe_download');

function maybe_download() {
  if (
    ! is_single() || empty($_POST) ||
    ! isset($_POST['resource']) || ! is_single($_POST['resource']) ||
    ! isset($_POST['email']) || ! is_email($_POST['email'])
   ) return;
   // get already saved emails from option
   $emails = get_option('subscribers') ? : array();
   if ( ! in_array($_POST['email'], $emails) ) {
     $emails[] = $_POST['email'];
     update_option('subscribers', $emails);
   }
   $res = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'resource', true);
   if ( empty($res) ) return;
   // avoid same user download again same file in the next 10 minutes
   if ( get_transient('downloaded_' . $_POST['email'] . '_' . $res) ) {
     wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
     exit();
   }
   // file path
   $file = trailingslashit( ABSPATH ) . 'resources/' . trim($res);
   if ( ! file_exists($file) ) return;
   // avoid same user download again same file in the next 10 minutes
   set_transient('downloaded_' . $_POST['email'] . '_' . $res, 1, 600 );
   // download count for the resource
   $count = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_download', true) ? : 0;
   update_post_meta($post->ID, '_download', $count+1);
   // force download of file
   header("Cache-Control: public");
   header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= " . basename($file) );
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   readfile($file);
   exit();
}
```

To retrieve all suscribers you have to: `get_option('subscribers')`.

With `get_post_meta($post->ID, '_download', true)` you can know how many time a file has been downloaded.

Again this is a very simple workflow, but you can use as starting point.

Please note that code is **completely untested**.