# How to prevent to direct access of my custom plugin folder/files

Tags: security

I want to write this code on my custom plugin main file to prevent to access folder/files.

```
define( 'FTEC_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what you're trying to achieve? Also your question doesn't contain any.

Comment: i made a custom plugin but there are one problem when we are put URL of plugin that are show all files and folder so how can i prevent this

Comment: Is this is related to web server setting not to allow visiting files in `wp-content`, `wp-admin`, `wp-include`?

Comment: @prosti So there are not any options/ function to prevent this

Comment: @prosti I also check another plugins that are not allow to direct access any files/folder

Comment: WordPress cannot control that like webserver can, htaccess can and nginx.conf can. Your plugin can have .htaccess

Comment: @prosti within plugin folder i don't have ant .htaccess file

Comment: Create one, but there are other web servers, not just Apache.

Comment: I've listed - I think - useful information on my [Q&A on restricted access to up-/downloads](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/100939/22534). Although it's older, the information should be valid overall. More information on what exactly you want to achieve would be helpful, so you might want to improve your question in that regard. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well. If I'm not wrong, you are looking for a way to hide what files are in your plugin directory?

Just keep an `index.php` file in your plugin directory.

And as an extra layer of security, add this code at the very beginning of all of your **PHP** files-

```
// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die();
}
```

Comment: I want to prevent my plugin file and i also want to write code in plugin code file

Comment: can you elaborate?