# Creating a custom multilingual form

Tags: forms, translation, plugin-qtranslate

I need to create a special form for my website where users cand specify a series of data including some textfields, combo boxes and sliders (from 0 to 100). Also I need this form to be qTranslate compatible, for my website is multilingual.

What would be the easiest, cheapest approach for this?

I tried the lite version of Ninja Forms plugin but it offers very few form element types.

I also started creating my own template with the form elements but I don't know how to make it work with qTranslate. And I'm thinking this solution is maybe reinventing the wheel and there's a fastest approach than programming it myself.

Comment: Note, plugin/theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) here.

Comment: I do not necessarily request a plugin or theme recommendation.

Comment: Could you try to make your question more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the easiest, cheapest approach for this?

Simple, create one form per language.

In `functions.php` or, preferably, as a [custom plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615):

```
add_shortcode( 'my-lingo-form', 'shortcode_wpse_98360');
function shortcode_wpse_98360()
{
    $lingo = your_language_detection_method();
    switch( $lingo )
    {
        case 'en':
            echo do_shortcode('[form-en]');
        break;
        default:
            echo do_shortcode('[form-other-languages]');
        break;
    }
}
```

In your post or page: `[my-lingo-form]`.