# Adding a template in WPTouch

Tags: themes, mobile, plugin-wptouch

I am creating a mobile version for a site. For that I am using WPTouch not WPTouch-Pro. Now I want to add a form in my page.

For desktop version I used template to add form. But in mobile version it's not working. When I exit mobile version form is present in my page. I saw some post which suggest to add child theme and its for WPTouch-Pro.

Since I am new to wordpress I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: @brasofilo  is there any other way to do this? i am using `theme  purity` for desktop version and the contact form is having many php code inside the form. url for purity contact form http://thetauris.com/themes/purity/?page_id=184

Comment: @brasofilo thanks for your suggestion. I have done it with shortcode. :)

Comment: RoSe, I converted my comment into an Answer and added a suggestion on how to run with `Restricted Mode` enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WPTouch uses its own theme, we can't hardcode certain functionality inside the regular theme, neither in a page/post template nor `functions.php`.

So, a [custom plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) is needed and the desired output made out of a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Also, make sure WPTouch `Restricted Mode` is turned off in *Advanced Options > Advanced Settings*. But probably this restricted mode can live together with a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).