# OG:Audio facebook meta tags

Tags: php, facebook, open-graph

Does anyone have any Idea how to populate the attached audio file URL into meta elements? Just as you would featured image or something Here's what I tried:

```
<meta property="og:audio" content="<?php $meta_values = get_post_custom($post->ID);
if(isset($meta_values['meta_audio_attachment'][0])){ $url =$meta_values['meta_audio_attachment'][0]; } ?>" />
<meta property="og:audio:title" content="Test" />
<meta property="og:audio:artist" content="Test" />
<meta property="og:audio:album" content="Test Album" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="application/mp3" />
```

Facebook populates all the rest of the meta's except the audio url?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using this code in your theme's `header.php`. When this file is loaded `$post` is not available yet (it'll be inside the Loop). So you'd need to declare before anything `global $post;`.

But that's not the best approach. If you swap themes, what? Do it again?
See: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

With the following plugin, we will hook into `wp_head` and print our meta based on some [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Print Audio OG */

add_action( 'wp_head', 'print_audio_og_wpse_99152', 0 );

function print_audio_og_wpse_99152()
{
    // Print only in single posts or pages
    if( is_single() || is_page() )
    {
        global $post;
        $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_audio_attachment', true );
        if( $meta_value )
            echo "
<meta property='og:audio' content='$meta_value' />
<meta property='og:audio:title' content='$post->post_title' />
<meta property='og:audio:artist' content='Test' />
<meta property='og:audio:album' content='Test Album' />
<meta property='og:audio:type' content='application/mp3' />
";
    }
}
```

You'll have to adapt `get_post_meta`.
Increase the hook priority, now `0` (zero), to move the insertion point in the rendered HTML.

Comment: Hmm so just put this into say "audioog" folder inside plugins and create index.php and put the code in? 

Or just add it to functions?  Also why do I have to adapt if its already actioning into wphead?

Comment: Yes, a simple plugin is very simple. No, don't add to functions, this is not a case for it. Adapt because you're using `get_post_custom`, grab the meta data as you wish/need.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking something simple,but I'm very confused. I thought "meta_audio_attachment“ was already done with global post?   global $post;
        $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_audio_attachment', true );

Comment: Show your full code.