# Display external RSS feed on pages

Tags: rss

i'm working on a website that is built on WordPress & the Genesis Framework. I'm looking to display an RSS feed [From Feedstich](http://assets3.feedstitch.com/12689/traffic-safety-news) within WordPress pages in the middle of the content. What is my best bet of doing this, is there a plugin that can use shortcodes or is there a way I can use php in pages to display them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a wrapper for `fetch_feed()` as a simple shortcode.

Very basic example; see the RSS widget code for more options.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Feed Shortcode
 * Description: Use <code>[feed url="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/feeds"]</code> to display a list of feed items.
 */

add_shortcode( 'feed', 't5_feed_shortcode' );

function t5_feed_shortcode( $attrs )
{
    $args = shortcode_atts(
        array (
            'url' => 'http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/feeds'
        ),
        $attrs
    );

    // a SimplePie instance
    $feed = fetch_feed( $args[ 'url' ] );

    if ( is_wp_error( $feed ) )
        return 'There was an error';

    if ( ! $feed->get_item_quantity() )
        return 'Feed is down.';

    $lis = array();

    foreach ( $feed->get_items(0, 20) as $item )
    {
        if ( '' === $title = esc_attr( strip_tags( $item->get_title() ) ) )
            $title = __( 'Untitled' );

        $lis[] = sprintf(
            '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( strip_tags( $item->get_link() ) ),
            $title
        );
    }

    return '<ul class="feed-list"><li>' . join( '</li><li>', $lis ) . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I think this makes sense, just add these lines of code to my functions file (or a custom plugin) then use the shortcodes? @torscho

Comment: The code is a complete plugin. Install, activate, and it works. [Never put a shortcode into a theme](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code straight from WordPress codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed:

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Recent news from Some-Other Blog:', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></h2>

<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://example.com/rss/feed/goes/here' );

$maxitems = 0;

if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 5 ); 

    // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

endif;
?>

<ul>
    <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
        <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
        <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"
                    title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_feed/