# Getting Custom Post Type content from main-site of a Multisite

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, multisite, wp-admin, network-admin

I have a multi-site network with 3 sub-sites:

[image]

Is it possible to "link" or include custom post to all 3 sites from the main site?

By include or link I don't mean to make other sites to edit them, I'm asking for the visual solution.

If possible, could I do that without using a plugin?

Comment: Without a plugin [does not exist](http://unserkaiser.com/code/without-a-plugin-the-functions-php-myth-a-comprehensive-user-guide/). Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the technique in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11387635/1957620), that's basically:

```
switch_to_blog(1); //switch to main site
$latest_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $latest_posts as $post ) {
    // print post
}
restore_current_blog();
```

Just add **`'post_type' => 'your-custom-post-type'`**  to the query.