# Adding custom image sizes and post types to a plugin or to a theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, themes, images

I'm just getting started but want to play around in the right area practicing for a new personal site/theme.

Part A: 
I want to add featured images (and a few new image sizes) to a blog portion of a theme. It feels like all this should be done in the child theme itself, right?

Part B:
I also want to add a portfolio page template with associated custom post type. (in a custom, plugin, correct?) Would it be ok to still include the page template in the theme?

Just looking for the best locations to add this, not the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

New image sizes need new rules in the stylesheet, so the best place for them is usually in the child theme. On the other hand: attachments *are* content, so the answer to your question depends on the specific use case. If you need these images in back-end only, or in a part of the front-end that is not affected by the default stylesheet (a slider, a light box), they can be placed in a plugin.

Custom post type registration belongs to plugins. See [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php). The *template* for this is usually a theme job.