# Should I use include or load_template for including shortcodes, plugins and so on?

Tags: theme-development, functions, include

I am wondering what is the right way to include additional php files for theme options, shortcodes, plugins and so on.

Both load_template and include will work, but what has better semantic value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load_template()` is for cases where you need the following global variables in an included file:

```
$posts, 
$post, 
$wp_did_header, 
$wp_query, 
$wp_rewrite, 
$wpdb, 
$wp_version, 
$wp, 
$id, 
$comment, 
$user_ID
```

If you don’t need those, or if you use `global` in those files anyway, it isn’t needed.

`locate_template()` and `get_template_part()` are for cases when you want to allow child themes to replace the files with their own version. If you offer other ways to turn the loading off, it isn’t needed.

So, it depends on the context, on the position of your theme in the hierarchy (parent or child), and on the included code. You can use `require` if you want to. Avoid `require_once` and `include_once`, they are more expensive.

And shortcodes are [not part of a good theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php). :)