# woocommerce download post-types\writepanels limits?

Tags: plugins

How can I change these codes so that the download limits are set and no one can change them on the add product side? Or hide them, so no one can see them?

```
// Download Limit
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
    'id' => '_download_limit', 
    'label' => __( 'Download Limit', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => __( 'Unlimited', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'description' => __( 'Leave blank for unlimited re-downloads.', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'type' => 'number', 
    'custom_attributes' => array(
        'step'  => '1',
        'min'   => '0'
    ) 
));

// Expirey
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
    'id' => '_download_expiry', 
    'label' => __( 'Download Expiry', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => __( 'Never', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'description' => __( 'Enter the number of days before a download link expires, or leave blank.', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'type' => 'number', 
    'custom_attributes' => array(
        'step'  => '1',
        'min'   => '0'
    ) 
));

do_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_downloads' );

echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to intercept the `get_post_meta('_download_limit')` and set a fixed value to it. When trying to save a different value it goes back to the fixed value:

```
add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', function( $value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single )
{
    if( '_download_limit' == $meta_key )
        $value = 100;

    return $value;
}, 10, 4 );
```

<sup>*See [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)*</sup>