# woocommerce: change default setting > is_sold_individualy function

Tags: functions, plugins

In woocommerce/classes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php on line 338.
The is_sold_individualy function is default "false".
Is there a way to set this default option to "true"? So in de Wordpress back-end the checkbox is checked by default?

```
 function is_sold_individually() {
    $return = false;

      if ( 'yes' == $this->sold_individually || ( ! $this->backorders_allowed() && $this->get_stock_quantity() == 1 ) ) {
         $return = true;
     }

      return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', $return, $this );
  }
```

Thanks in advance,
Mirjam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a built-in function from WordPress:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );
```

This line [in a separate plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) will set the value always to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You want it to be true *all* the time?  The `apply_filters()` is your tip off that you can modify this value for any or all products.

```
function wpa_119087_always_sold_individually( $individually, $product ){
  $individually = true;
  return $individually;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wpa_119087_always_sold_individually', 10, 2 );
```