# Multilingual Wordpress page - using URL to determine language?

Tags: query, multi-language, language

I want to create a webpage that supports more than one language, but I don't want to use a plugin for that if it's possible.

I am already loading the theme translation depending on the URL; if there is a '/en' part at the end (but before get-parameters), I load the english translation etc.

Is it possible and wise to also change the query depending on that parameter?

Meaning that if '/en' is found, all loaded posts need to be tagged with 'English', if '/br' is found all posts need to be tagged with 'Brazil' (standing for brazilian portuguese) and so on.

Comment: You might want to look at multisite/network installs [and other questions about that topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=multi+language+site) here on this site.

Comment: This is pure plugin territory. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php