# Custom Post Types. Are there any disadvantages/advantages in using a plugin to develop them?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, post-meta, performance

There are a few plugins which can assist you in building your CPT's, and these can usually handle your taxonomies and sometimes postmeta also. Some even take it further than that. I know that as with any plugin it's possible that development may cease; but aside from that are there any reasons why it's better to code your own CPT's taxonomies etc.

**Here are some of the plugins I'm referring to**

- Custom Post Type UI
- Types
- WCK
- Custom Post Type Maker

**Here's my Advantage/Disadvantage list**

*Advantages*

- Quicker and Easier
- Developers have hopefully considered security so
  no need to worry about nonces or protecting the database etc

*Disadvantages*

- Might be a performance issue for some applications
- Depending on
  development to continue.
- Possibly Less Flexible

Does anyone want to add to or take away from this list?

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion and not a question which has a correct answer. also, there's nothing exploitable in a simple `register_post_type` call, on the contrary, who knows what additional, exploitable code these plugins may contain, so that item should be moved to the *disadvantages* column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no really huge difference, you choose the tool that you feel most comfortable yourself. Plugins have the drawbacks you mentioned, and doing them from scratch can be a bit slow and tedious.

The 3rd alternative, that I find really good, is a PHP class that does all the heavy lifting for you, but is still light and easy to use, e.g. [Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types). This particular class does custom taxonomies and metaboxes also. Very handy. So you'll eliminate bunch of plugins with one hit.

Comment: Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types dead link. Too bad.

Answer (score -1):

This really isn't a good question. But if you're a developer you really should register your own custom post types in the functions.php file of the theme you're using.

look at the template below:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_[post_name]' );
function register_cpt_[post_name]() {
$labels = array(
'name'               => '[post name]',
'singular_name'      => '[singular post name]',
'add_new'            => 'Add New',
'add_new_item'       => 'Add New [post name]',
'edit_item'          => 'Edit [post name]',
'new_item'           => 'New [post name]',
'all_items'          => 'All [post name]',
'view_item'          => 'View [post name]',
'search_items'       => 'Search [post name]',
'not_found'          => 'No [post name] found',
'not_found_in_trash' => 'No [post name] in Trash',
'parent_item_colon'  => '',
'menu_name'          => '[post name as it will appear in the WP dashboard]'
);

$args = array(
'labels'             => $labels,
'public'             => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui'            => true,
'show_in_menu'       => true,
'query_var'          => true,
'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => '[post-name]' ),
'capability_type'    => 'post',
'has_archive'        => true,
'hierarchical'       => false,
'menu_position'      => null,
'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt',     'comments' )
);
register_post_type('[post_name]', $args);
};
```

Comment: Please, no. [Never register post types in a theme](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).