# How to hide Admin Tabs?

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu

I'm trying to hide tabs of admin panel like Posts, Pages, etc...

I tried [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) without success.

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic in most of [se]. I've removed this part from your post to acomodate it. Anyway, you should research here, there are *plenty of solutions*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code (below is just *an example* for 3 random tabs)

```
function disable_user_profile() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) { 
        wp_redirect( admin_url('index.php') ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'disable_user_profile' ); // disable profile tab
add_action( 'load-tools.php', 'disable_user_profile' ); // disable tools tab
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'disable_user_profile' ); // disable posts tab
```

The `if ( !current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )`  = user capability 
The `wp_redirect( admin_url('index.php') );` = I put here so they stay in backend, even if they try to add the link to that page in url
The `add_action( 'load-profile.php',` = tab which should not be accessible.(in this case the profile tab)

If I am correct then the sample here disables the tabs for Contributor and Subscriber.

---

**Edit**
Assuming you won't use this only for your theme but for the whole backend (So it is active also when switching theme's) a sample plugin with the code is to find below.
Create a file ie. disable_tabs.php , and use the code below (it is incl. the above sample).

```
<?php
*Plugin Name: Hide Tabs in Admin panel
*Description: Hiding tabs for certain user levels.
*Author Name: Who ever you want
*
    function disable_user_profile() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) { 
        wp_redirect( admin_url('index.php') ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'disable_user_profile' ); // disable profile tab
add_action( 'load-tools.php', 'disable_user_profile' ); // disable tools tab
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'disable_user_profile' ); // disable posts tab
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031)

Comment: Made some changes, Brasofilo is right about not using it in just one theme but "system wide". (Personally I would place it in mu-plugins, but thats just me)