# Get a sidebar at the top of the page

Tags: sidebar, custom-header

I want to get a sidebar ( `get_sidebar( 'mySidebar' )` ) at the top of the page, so I can't call it after `get_header()` in the content template. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works from your child themes `functions.php` file.

Change the hook to a different position:

```
//functions.php
function wpsites_register_widget() {

 register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'After Header Widget',
'id' => 'after-header',
'before_widget' => '<div>',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
) );
}

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpsites_register_widget' );

    add_filter( 'loop_start', 'after_header_widget', 25 );

    function after_header_widget() {


    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'after-header' ) ) { 
    dynamic_sidebar('after-header', array(
    'before' => '<div class="after-header">',
    'after' => '</div>',
) );


    }

}
```

Or you can [call the sidebar directly in your template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar).

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'after-header' ) ) : ?>
<ul id="after-header">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'after-header' ); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I've tried, but the sidebar is called after the navigation bar. I want to call it before.

Comment: Use the template code before the nav

Comment: Well, I thought that overriding `header.php` file wasn't a recommended method.

Comment: It is fine to create a header.php in your child theme. It might not be ideal and you should review your header.php to see if there are any hooks you might be able to add `after_header_start()` to. Impossible to say without seeing your header.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, call it after `get_header()`.
Make sure `sidebar-{name}.php` i.e `sidebar-mySidebar.php` file is present.
Otherwise let me know the error.

Comment: The problem is that I want to call it before all the elements in the page, so calling it after `header` will put the sidebar content below the "nav-bar".

Comment: then you can copy header.php file and call sidebar before navigation menu.