# Warning after create Custom post type with Roots theme

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-roots

I've created e Custom post type with Roots theme,
adding the custom script inside functions.php like

```
require_once locate_template('/lib/custom-post-types.php');          // Custom post types
```

After that in backend the list of pages is not displayed, and in frontend show this Warning:

> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /wordpress/wp-includes/query.php on line 2375
>
> Warning: urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /wordpress/wp-includes/post.php on line 3901
>
> Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3690

What could be?

Comment: Is this a problem with the `locate_template()` function or with the code in custom-post-types.php? It sounds like `locate_template()` needs another parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was a problem with the custom-post-types.php I was calling the type with the name `'post_type'` changed that solved the issue.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Please do accept this answer, it will mean this question is marked as solved :)

Answer (score -2):

Create custom post type by writing below code in function.php file located in Apperance => Editor . This  code is very simple example of custom post type.

```
// custom post type function
function create_posttype() {

register_post_type( 'movies',
// CPT Options
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),
    )
);
 }
 // Hooking up function for theme setup
  add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Reference : [How to Create Custom Post Types in WordPress – WordPress Tutorial](http://codemarts.com/blog/create-custom-post-types-wordpress-wordpress-tutorial-part7/)

Comment: [**Never**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/73) register custom post types in theme files.

Comment: Never ever use the backend editor. There is no syntax highlighting or code editor build in. One tiny syntax error, and your site is broken. Also, as @toscho suggested, custom post types **should** go into a plugin and **not** in your theme