# Add "Last Edited by" column to custom post type list table

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, columns

Currently I use the "Admin Columns Pro" plugin for Wordpress to modify some of the columns in the backend. The plugin contains functionality to display the post (or in my case, product) author as a column.

However, I'm in a position where I need to see who the most recent editor of the product is. Basically what we've got now is one individual creates a product draft, then someone finishes it, and I need to see both of those names (one creator, and one the_modified_author).

The plugin contains [documentation to create custom columns](http://www.admincolumns.com/documentation/how-to/register-column/), and I've tried to follow it, but I can't seem to get ["the_modified_author"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_author) to pass through.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just FYI, I'm looking to extend functionality via a theme edit, rather than a plugin... both avenues are covered in the documentation I linked to above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Changing admin columns [belongs to a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php), not to a theme file, because themes should never change anything else than frontend output. You can get the complete plugin here: **[Plugin Product Editor Column](https://gist.github.com/thefuxia/8e94ebb272d35d1dc54c)**.

Looking at the docs you linked to, I see the plugin author requires a child class that mixes multiple separate tasks. That’s not good. We will see in a minute why.

On the other hand, we are not in the *plugin support business* anyway. We are in the *Find your own solution business*. So let’s ignore that plugin and look at the core functions.

[image]

- Column **headers** for post types are registered on the filter `"manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns"`. For a post type `product` this would be `"manage_product_posts_columns"`.
- The column **content** can be printed on the action `"manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column"`.

These are very poor names: They don’t really tell us what happens here.

Both hooks are called when the file `wp-admin/edit.php` is loaded, so we wait until the action `'load-edit.php'` fires.

On the edit page, we look into the object returned by `get_current_screen()`: If its `id` property matches `"edit-$post_type"`, we register our callbacks.

The `"manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns"` filter gives us an array of the existing column headers. We just add an entry and return the array back:

```
function add_column( Array $columns )
{
    $columns[ 'modified_author' ] = 'Last modified by';

    return $columns;
}
```

The `"manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column"` action gives us the `$column_name` and the `$post_id`. We compare the column name with our earlier registered name `'modified_author'`, because there might be other custom columns, and we don’t want to touch them. If the given column name is ours, we use the `$post_id` to get the ID of the last author who modified the post:

```
$last_id   = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_edit_last', TRUE );
$last_user = get_userdata( $last_id );
print esc_html( $last_user->display_name );
```

The short version of our code could look like this:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() {

    $post_type   = 'product';
    $col_name    = 'modified_author';

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( ! isset ( $screen->id ) )
        return;

    if ( "edit-$post_type" !== $screen->id )
        return;

    add_filter(
        "manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns",
        function( $posts_columns ) use ( $col_name ) {
            $posts_columns[ $col_name ] = 'Last modified by';

            return $posts_columns;
        }
    );

    add_action(
        "manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column",
        function( $column_name, $post_id ) use ( $col_name ) {

            if ( $col_name !== $column_name )
                return;

            $last_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_edit_last', TRUE );

            if ( ! $last_id ) {
                print '<i>Unknown</i>';
                return;
            }

            $last_user = get_userdata( $last_id );

            print esc_html( $last_user->display_name );
        },
        10, 2
    );
});
```

**This works, but it isn’t good.**

- We cannot **reuse** that code to add the same column to posts or pages or something else.
- We cannot **test** the code, because everything happens in one call.
- [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) doesn’t happen. We are mixing too many different tasks:

  - Registering the callbacks
  - Validating the column name
  - Fetching the value from the post meta table
  - Printing the escaped output of the column

Let’s improve our code!

Registering the callbacks should be done by a *Controller*. It doesn’t have to know where we get our data from and how we print them to the user’s screen, so pass those as **abstract dependencies**:

```
class Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Column_Data
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @var Column_View
     */
    private $view;

    /**
     * @param Column_Data $data
     * @param Column_View $view
     */
    public function __construct( Column_Data $data, Column_View $view ) {

        $this->data = $data;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        $screen    = get_current_screen();
        $post_type = $this->data->get_post_type();

        if ( ! isset ( $screen->id ) )
            return;

        if ( "edit-$post_type" !== $screen->id )
            return;

        add_filter(
            "manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns",
            [ $this->data, 'add_column' ]
        );

        add_action(
            "manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column",
            [ $this->view, 'render_column' ],
            10, 2
        );
    }
}
```

`Column_Data` and `Column_View` are [interfaces](http://wpkrauts.com/2013/how-to-build-flexible-php-interfaces/), not concrete classes, so we can reuse that controller with different data providers or output handlers. Let’s build these interfaces.

The interface for the data needs methods to

- add the column headers
- get the content (author display name for example)
- tell the controller what post type it handles and
- the view if it operates in the correct column when it is called

```php
interface Column_Data
{
    /**
     * @param array $columns
     * @return array
     */
    public function add_column( Array $columns );

    /**
     * @param  int    $post_id
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_column_content( $post_id );

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_post_type();

    /**
     * @param $column_name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is_valid_column( $column_name );
}
```

The output/view object needs just one method:

```
interface Column_View
{
    /**
     * @param  string $column_name
     * @param  int    $post_id
     * @return void
     */
    public function render_column( $column_name, $post_id );
}
```

The view has to fetch some information from the data model, so pass an instance to the constructor of the concrete class:

```
class Last_Mod_Author_Column_Output implements Column_View
{
    /**
     * @var Column_Data
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @param Column_Data $data
     */
    public function __construct( Column_Data $data )
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $column_name
     * @param  int    $post_id
     * @return void
     */
    public function render_column( $column_name, $post_id )
    {
        if ( ! $this->data->is_valid_column( $column_name ) )
            return;

        $content = $this->data->get_column_content( $post_id );

        if ( '' === $content )
            print '<i>Unknown</i>';
        else
            print esc_html( $content );
    }
}
```

The data model has to know the post type, so we pass that to the concrete class’ constructor:

```
class Last_Mod_Author_Column_Data implements Column_Data
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $post_type;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $column_name = 'modified_author';

    /**
     * @param string $post_type
     */
    public function __construct( $post_type )
    {
        $this->post_type = $post_type;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $columns
     * @return array
     */
    public function add_column( Array $columns )
    {
        $columns[ $this->column_name ] = 'Last modified by';

        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * @param  int    $post_id
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_column_content( $post_id )
    {
        $last_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_edit_last', TRUE );

        if ( ! $last_id ) {
            return '';
        }

        $last_user = get_userdata( $last_id );

        return $last_user->display_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_post_type()
    {
        return $this->post_type;
    }

    /**
     * @param $column_name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is_valid_column( $column_name )
    {
        return $this->column_name === $column_name;
    }
}
```

And now we can use these classes:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() {

    $model      = new Last_Mod_Author_Column_Data( 'product' );
    $view       = new Last_Mod_Author_Column_Output( $model );
    $controller = new Controller( $model, $view );

    $controller->setup();
});
```

We can use the same code for pages with just a tiny change:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() {

    $model      = new Last_Mod_Author_Column_Data( 'page' );
    $view       = new Last_Mod_Author_Column_Output( $model );
    $controller = new Controller( $model, $view );

    $controller->setup();
});
```

**Why is this rather long code better?**

We could implement the data interface in a class that fetches the value from another table or a text file or an external API – without any change to the controller or the view.

We could use a view that makes the author name bold or uses a different fallback – without changing the controller or the data model.

We can test all public methods of all classes by providing dummy objects for the dependencies (stubs).

We avoid the [fragile base class problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class), because we don’t use inheritance like the author of the plugin you mentioned.

Comment: Instantly reminded me about your [comment](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/buddypress-question-flagged-as-off-topic-on-wordpress-se#comment5549_3900) yesterday.

Comment: @ialocin Ha, yes. :) Plus, I love to answer questions with unjustified close votes.

Comment: Lets see, oh yea, I close voted this.. :) Retracted it now, besides the question was about the plugin, not how to do this and what has been done to achieve it. Hm, I missed that comment under the question..

Comment: +1, but I don't really get why `Last_Mod_Author_Column_Data` has a `private` and fixed property `$column_name`. Why not at least having this as second (optional) argument on the constructor? Was the answer already too long? ;)

Comment: @kaiser That’s internal logic. You _could_ make it dynamic, but then you have to ask yourself why you have two columns with that name.

Comment: Read it after the initial quick read again. I guess with `name` you are referring to the Column Header Label?

Comment: @kaiser The column key. The visible label has to be called as late as possible anyway to enable lazy translation loading, something I left out here deliberately.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this. It's much appreciated. If I may continue on my noob-rant, are all of these segments of code (as defined above as the "improved code") all inserted in the edit.php file? I was thinking the functions.php would be used, but nowhere above did you mention that. Finally, if these edits do indeed go in the edit.php (within /wp-admin) what keeps them from just being overwritten with the next WP update? Thanks again.

Comment: @itwasluck3 The code goes to a separate plugin. I have added a not and a link at the top of my answer.

Comment: @toscho thanks for spelling that out for me. Last thing: Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/my-website/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Product-Last-edited-by/product-editor-column.php on line 187

Comment: @itwasluck3 Your PHP version is too old. Make sure you have _at least_ PHP 5.4. Older versions don’t get security updates anymore, they are vulnerable. And much slower.

Comment: @toscho shortly after posting I figured this was the problem as  I'm on 5.3.28 currently... Thanks again!

Comment: @toscho Co-author of Admin Columns Pro here. We use the structure we use because a plugin used by thousands of people around the world shouldn't only be structured properly, it should also be very easy to use. We've had to make a few minor tradeoffs (for example, we indeed *do* have the fragile base class problem), but it does ensure a big part of our users can extend our plugin. (Do *love* your answer by the way and would love to discuss this! I've sent you a tweet.)