# How to add a new column in custom post type list?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a new custom post type (gallery) and a new taxonomy for gallery categories (gallery_category) by using [this code](http://pastebin.com/GKq0KWAb).

New post type & categories works, but **i want to show the category of posts in custom post list in admin panel** like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cscvv.png).

How can i do this?

Comment: Please use our search engine. We have dozens of good solutions for this.

Comment: dear  @toscho i searched but did not find.
might be i understand page name. if you know solution, say how ?

Comment: Here is one example that I have written myself: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/157223/73 Instead of `get_post_meta()` you fetch the categories for the post, that's the main change you have to make.

Comment: I also have an example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268829/add-a-custom-column-in-users-list-page/268835). You should however change the `users` to `posts` in the filter.