# Is a custom post type considred a plugin?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, taxonomy

I am reading up on custom post types and taxonomies. I am new to Wordpress development, and just trying to get a firm grasp on custom post types. Upon creating a custom post type:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Movie Reviews
Plugin URI: http://wp.tutsplus.com/
Description: Declares a plugin that will create a custom post type displaying movie reviews.
Version: 1.0
Author: Soumitra Chakraborty
Author URI: http://wp.tutsplus.com/
License: GPLv2
*/
?>
```

I'm assuming this is the standard way to create one. So is it considered a custom authored plugin?

Comment: Custom post types are posts, these are not plugins. But as stated in your plugin description, you can create custom post type from plugin which is recommended because custom post types are usually websites property not themes.

Comment: It just seemed like it was insinuated that a CPT is a form of a plugin because of how it's created in this tutorial.  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes--wp-27645

Comment: It's not necessary to create CPT from plugin (you can add it from theme too) but using plugin is better way. It's also website/project specific. For example if your website have a CPT for `Movies` section then you should create it with plugin because if you change theme on your website then you would not worry about flushing all custom post types. But let's say if you are creating a slideshow with CPT then you can register your CPT in theme too. In short if CPT is adding functionality to website then it should go in plugin and if it's used to add appearance then it can also go in theme.

Comment: See [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php)

Comment: @Roberthue thanks that explains it. Not sure why you didn't put this answer as a an answer I would have marked it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I am glad I could help. Also, as suggested by @PieterGoosen [read this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/31545), it was explained very well.

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer to your question is that a custom post type is not considered a plugin, in the same way that posts and pages are not considered plugins, but are a 'type' of post. However a plugin can be used to create and manage custom post types.