# how to echo meta tag in header using php

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I need to display a meta tag in header for singular custom post type "communications" like this:

```
<meta name="citation_title" content="single post title is here" />
```

I tried to use this code :

```
<?php if ( is_singular( 'communications' ) ) {
        echo '<meta name="citation_title" content="' . the_title( '', '' ).'" />' . '';
} ?>
```

but the result was a title before the meta:

```
single post title is here<meta name="citation_title" content="" />
```

any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `the_title_attribute()` to print the attribute. A post title might contain HTML, so you need the escaped content that this function returns.
Also suppress immediate print-out, because that will set the output in front of the `echo` statement.

```
if ( is_singular( 'communications' ) ) {
    $title = the_title_attribute( [ 'echo' => FALSE ] );
    echo '<meta name="citation_title" content="' . $title . '" />' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Another question is why your theme knows so much about the post type. [Custom post types should always be registered in a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/73). So that code should go to the plugin too. This is how the result could look like:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_citation_title' );

function add_citation_title() {

    if ( ! is_singular( 'communications' ) )
        return;

    $title = the_title_attribute( [ 'echo' => FALSE ] );
    echo '<meta name="citation_title" content="' . $title . '" />' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: you are great thanks a lot but I have another question please: when i use several codes, like your first one, to display several meta tags the result is displayed in one single row. how can i put each meta tag in one row please?

Comment: @nisr Add `. PHP_EOL`. See my edit.

Comment: It worked !! You are the best, thank you very much