# How can I prevent a plugin from searching for updates?

Tags: updates

I'm interested in using an old version of a plugin for a core feature on the site (it's not ideal but a compromise after months of effort) because the new version has incompatibilities. However I'm worried that someone - including myself - will mindlessly update the plugin in the future.

Is there any way to prevent a WordPress plugin from searching for updates?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple. All you have to do is add some code in a Custom Functions plugin.

Lets say you want to block the "Hello Dolly" plugin (comes prepacked with WordPress) from updating. In your "My Functions Plugin", `mycustomfunctions.php` (you can use any name really) you place the following:

```
/* Disable a plugin from updating */
function disable_plugin_updating( $value ) {
   unset( $value->response['hello.php'] );
   return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updating' );
```

That is all.
Now in case you want to prevent more than one plugins from updating, you just add additional lines to the above code like this:

```
/* Disable some plugins from updating */
function disable_plugin_updating( $value ) {
   unset( $value->response['hello.php'] );
   unset( $value->response[ 'akismet/akismet.php' ] );
   return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updating' );
```

**Things to notice**:

- It is always best practice to **keep everything updated to the latest version** (for obvious reasons and mainly for vulnerability issues).
- We use `akismet/akismet.php` because `akismet.php` is within the plugin folder `akismet`
- In case you are not aware of what a Custom Functions plugin is (or don't have one) you can easily create one. Please have a look at an old -but still very valid- post on: [Creating a custom functions plugin for end users](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users).
- Also, please have a look at this post about: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily stop WordPress plugins from searching for updates just with this code:

```
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
unset( $value->response['PATH_TO_PLUGIN_MAIN_FILE'] ); //Replace the path with main PHP file of your plugin.
return $value;}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
```

I have written a complete blog post on it. Here is my blog post - [Prevent a WordPress plugin from searching for updates](https://www.codespeedy.com/prevent-a-wordpress-plugin-from-searching-for-updates/). This blog will show you how and wheere to use this blog. And also give you the suggestion to use it in perfect place.

Source: https://www.codespeedy.com/prevent-a-wordpress-plugin-from-searching-for-updates/

Comment: Could you please explain how is this different from the other answer? Apart of the fact that you link to your post?

Answer (score 0):

One-Line version is also good to insert into current plugin's construction:

```
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', function ($value) { if ( isset($value->response[$name=plugin_basename(__FILE__)]) ) { unset($value->response[$name]); }   return $value; });
```