# Is wp_mail plugin territory?

Tags: theme-development, wp-mail

I recently stumbled upon this and was wondering if calling `wp_mail()` in a theme is allowed or not as per WordPress standards. I should clarify that I'm not overriding it as a pluggable function in the theme, I am just calling it if it exists.

I'm asking here because I've been searching for this but did not find any clear answer stating anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides a lot of functions you can use, including the `wp_mail()` function. The function is not only a plugin territory, the core uses it often.

If you will change the behavior, use [the filter and actions hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters) that are inside the core to influence the behavior of the function. As example for this function give it the filter hook `wp_mail`, see [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c2d709e9d6cbe7f9b3c37da0a7c9aae788158124/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L184) in the source. That is a possibility to change the behavior of `wp_mail()`.

The `wp_mail()` function is also pluggable and can be replaced by a new function with the same name. All functions in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` have a check if the function exists. That gives developers the chance to replace the function with changes to the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

While `wp_mail()` is not exactly forbidden in a theme, it is very likely misplaced there. [The purpose of a theme is presentation.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/73) It should not change existing data, and it should always be easy to replace.

That's the reason why contact forms, polls, shops, tracking and similar functionality is pure plugin territory. There is no context for `wp_mail()` in a theme.

Comment: It's interesting, since this wordpress author who seems reputable writes the contrary: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623: "Pluggable functions are something you code into your parent theme, so they won't be any use to you if you're working with an existing parent theme that doesn't have them."

Comment: @AlexC I am talking about `wp_mail()` only, not about pluggable functions in general. Albeit that is a **terrible** concept.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with calling `wp_mail()` in a theme.  It's a core function that is meant to be used.