# Exporting Custom Taxonomy Description without Plugin

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have registered/created custom taxonomy using CPTUI and added descriptions to terms. I can export and import CPT/CPT Taxonomies but getting no clue to import export the custom taxonomy terms.

A pluginless guidance will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: You mean per command line, like a SQL statement?

Comment: A guide to that will be helping. I can integrate that as a option in my custom theme... any reference? I have not dealt with db directly while working with wordpress.

Comment: Please do not put that logic into a theme. Themes should [deal with presentation only](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).

Comment: I agree to your point. Its kind of personal theme and would handle as if it is backing up everything in xml.

Comment: Is there any plugin code to do that? @fuxia