# Consolidate plugin functionality into a theme

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have several plugins installed into a theme a created. I was wondering if it was possible to integrate the codes from all the plugins into my theme so i can export it as one file. That way if i install my theme on another location i dont need to install the plugins anymore.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Plugin updates won't work anymore, theme switch is broken, debugging becomes a nightmare and so on. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php

Comment: So much what toscho said. Really, really bad idea.

Comment: However, you can install a recommended/install plugins script of the sort you'll increasingly find out there. I've seen at least one very contemporary theme that recommends a long list of plugins, well over ten, and a routine for installing them selectively. They can create problems of their own (like special plugins that break other themes if not uninstalled), but on balance I think it's a good alternative.