# Is there a way in WordPress to convert images to WebP without a plugin?

Tags: images, uploads, media, media-library

I'm building a simple WordPress theme for personal use. Speed is important.
My Google PageSpeed Score is high, but it keeps saying that I should use WebP, rather than JPG. ('modern web formats').

As I've built my theme completely from scratch, so that it only contains the bare necessities and no other unneeded things.

I would very much like not to use a plugin for this, but do it myself. So I came up with the following:

1. Upload JPG/PNG
2. WordPress creates all the image sizes *twice*: once in JPG/PNG (the original format) and once in WebP
3. When the page is loaded, I check whether to call the WebP version (when the browser supports it) or the original.

I already Googled a lot about webp in WordPress, but I only found out about plugins. I found this unanswered question with sample code for converting JPG/PNG to WebP, but I don't know if this is really correct. To me it seems like only the extension is changed. Does anybody know if that's also correct?

How do I add image sizes and convert an additional set to WebP?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "How do I add image sizes that convert to WebP?" - you've already stated that there are plugins that are capable of doing this. Why not check out how they solve it? Personally, I oppose your thinking and will gladly use plugins for anything non-trivial. Especially since WebP Express does a great job of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @kero thanks for reading through it. I agree that my last question was formulated a bit weird, so I changed that a bit better. I always prefer to not use prefer, since that always comes with an additional load and things you don't need. If I use a plugin for everything non-trivial, WordPress would be _significantly slower_.

Comment: But this task **is** plugin territory, whether you write your own or take something that exists.

Comment: Ok @fuxia good that you point that out. Do you also have an explanation why this is plugin territory? I mean, image sizes etc are also registered in my functions.php, so why not register an additional ‘upload function’ there? It’s really theme specific..

Comment: You might want to use these images after a theme switch, and themes should do as little as possible – [only the tasks related to presentation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/73).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if GD is enabled you can use PHP

```
$path = 'YOUR_PATH_TO_IMAGES';
$pngFile = 'name.png';
$webpFile = 'name.webp';

$image = imagecreatefrompng($path . $pngFile);
imagepalettetotruecolor($image );
imagealphablending($image , true);
imagesavealpha($image , true);
imagewebp($image , $path . $webpFile , 100);
imagedestroy($image );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I’m going to test it out this afternoon/tomorrow. Will let you know how it does!

Comment: Hey ktscript, sorry for being so awfully late! Thanks anyway